# Are Sci-Hub links to references in answers welcome?

Tags: discussion

A [recent answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/a/48402/36637) uses Sci-Hub links to make the sources available to the readers. [According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sci-Hub), Sci-Hub is a rather controversial service:

> Sci-Hub is a website that provides free access to millions of research papers and books, without regard to copyright, by bypassing publishers' paywalls in various ways. […] Sci-Hub and Elbakyan were sued twice for copyright infringement in the United States in 2015 and 2017, and lost both cases by default, leading to loss of some of its Internet domain names.

Is the use of Sci-Hub links welcome on skeptics.SE?

EDIT: @BrianZ pointed out in a comment that there is a similar question on [Space Exploration SE](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/whats-our-policy-on-sci-hub-links). One of the answers is in favor of Sci-Hub links (the top-voted answer), while the other answer (posted by a site moderator) recommends using DOI links, but no Sci-Hub links.

Comment: A very similar question arose on the Space Exploration meta a couple of years before this question was asked, https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1033/. We finally got a reply from JNat, a StackExchange Community Manager: "While we don't have hard legal blocks, this answer is in line with our recommendation — avoid URLs to sites which host illegal content if possible, as linking to these may harm the site's SEO in the long run, which could cause the need for tougher legal restrictions to be put in place." This referred to my answer that suggested that sci-hub links not be allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tricky one.

Sci-Hub is not just controversial, but appears to be violating the law.

Now that is a different question about whether it is *unethical*. I don't want to weigh in with my opinion on that, because I see it as a personal political opinion, I respect that others may differ and I don't think it should be reflected in the site's policies.

In reality, those of us who want to evade paywalls and infringe copyright are going to do so anyway. If they want to encourage others to do so, I think they should take that to Twitter, Reddit, personal blogs, letters to the editor and the voting booth. It seems reasonable that they don't trick those of us who want to support the commercial scientific journals into using such services.

Which brings me to my proposed answer.

- First, I recommend that the DOI is included. This protects against link rot when individual publishers web-sites change or disappear. (Sci-Hub URLs are constantly changing due to legal challenges, so only having a Sci-Hub link will likely lead to link rot very quickly.)
- Second, a link to Sci-Hub is, itself, a radical expression of personal politics. In keeping with our desire to minimise the expression of party/personal politics here, I would therefore recommend avoiding such links.

Comment: I used the term "controversial" instead of "illegal" because as far as I know, copyright laws are mostly national laws, so there may be many juristrictions where the service offered by Sci-Hub is legal after all.

Comment: @Schmuddi: I would point to the 176 countries who signed the [Berne Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berne_Convention), but I would very, very quickly be out of my depth at the first prodding, so I am keeping my mouth shut.

Comment: +1 ethics, legality, etc., are all subjective. Link rot is the most important reason to not use Sci-Hub in an answer. Pretty much everybody who has read a scientific journal knows about sci-hub so they can figure it out for themselves.

Answer (score 5):

I read the answer containing the Sci-Hub links during my coffee break in my office at my university, using my work computer. I didn't check the links before clicking, and I didn't expect a reputable website like the SE network to direct me routinely to a site that may be infringing copyright laws. By clicking on the links in the answer I may have easily violated the terms of service of my university network by using an illegal website. In short, I regret following the links in the answer – and I don't think that a practice that makes you regret clicking on the links in a highly upvoted answer is a good practise for skeptics.SE.

If linking to Sci-Hub is considered acceptable, I'll have to go through the following steps in the future if I want to continue reading skeptics.SE articles during my coffee break:

- check whether the link to an article is actually a Sci-Hub link
- copy the link URL
- open a new browser tab
- edit the URL to remove the Sci-Hub part
- proceed to the website of the original publisher

If the Sci-Hub links are in a format from which the original publisher's website cannot be recovered, I won't be able to read the sources from my work computer in the first place.

While I see the advantages of having immediate access to the sources used in an article without having to worry about a paywall, and regardless of whether I've ever used Sci-Hub in private before, I would prefer that skeptics.SE users refrain from using that website. If they do use Sci-Hub links in their questions and answers, I'd ask them at least to place a warning in their texts so that their readers don't accidentally download copyrighted material from an illegal website.

Comment: "NSFW" markings!